# Debug Assertion Failed in C, Not Sure What's Causing It

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on an assignment and I'm pretty much done, but I've run into a roadblock. I'm trying to print out all the "emirp" numbers my program generates, but if I try to print after running my EMIRP finding loop, it causes a Debug Assertion Failed error with this message.

[image]

Here's the program source.

http://pastebin.com/f81rE4hb

I'm a C++ guy in transition to using C, so maybe it's a C-specific problem causing it. If you need an explanation of anything, just ask. I'm compiling this with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Comment: Post the *problematic* code Here.

Comment: The assert failure is pointing to line 1034 of a particular source file, `output.c`. The code link seems to be something different.

Comment: output.c is not part of my program. I'm guessing it's part of the C library.

Comment: std C libs (well at least in non-windows world) dont generally use asserts internally... they just return NULL or -1 or 0 or what ever the doc says and optionally set an error somewhere... what is at the line of the source file that it indicates as the failure?

Comment: I figured out how to get VS to show me the file. Apparently, it's coming from this line.

#ifndef _UNICODE
    _VALIDATE_STREAM_ANSI_RETURN(stream, EINVAL, EOF);

Answer (score 2):

In my case it had to do with mixing unicode main program with non unicode external library written in C. This is what helped to me. Before calling first printf in external library I had to change console mode to ansi. After external library call I had to set mode back to unicode:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT);
....
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do `emirps++`:

1. You won't be able to free the memory that you've initially allocated, since `emirps` no longer points to the beginning of that memory.
2. You most certainly can't go about passing `emirps[i]` to `printf` (or any other function for that matter) at that point.

BTW, just noticed that there's a "whole bunch of mallocs" in your code not being freed anywhere...

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that... I changed it so it now just uses [] notation to assign values to the places in memory, but the error remains. I don't think that had anything to do with it.